# Load content in DIV on mouseclick

Tags: php, jquery

I have three pages

- *index.php*
- *postList.php*
- *postContent.php*

*postList.php* shows the list of posts and *postContent.php* shows the content within the post, comments etc.

I have loaded *postList.php* to a `div` in my *index.php* page and would like to load *postContent.php* to another `div` on the same page (*index.php*) when a link in *postList.php* is clicked.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not sure how many posts you are loading but you could try something with javascript. Just load it all and set a display:none class for the content. This way only the list of posts shows on load. When a list item is clicked, toggle the hidden state of  content.

Comment: @RST sorry not sure I explained it properly. so the postList.php gets the list of posts from a database and I've used jquery to load it to a div in index.php when a button is clicked and each post in the list has a link which takes you to postContent.php but instead of loading postContent.php as a new page I want it to appear on index,php in another div.

Comment: If you have 1k+ posts, you probably do not want to load all content, in that case you can use an AJAX request to retrieve the content, and put it wherever you want.
If you have 20 posts, you can load the post titles and the content, but put the content in a hidden div. On click of the title you can either make the content visible as it is or leave it hidden and copy the content to the div you have ready for this. It is easier when you show your code, and share more specifics of the scenario.